# htmlのvideoタグのソースについて

Tags: html

下のようにhtmlが書かれているとき、videoのソース(url、ファイルのパス)はどれですか？

```
<video class="gifVideo js-gifVideo lazyVideo" 
    data-webm="https://el.phncdn.com/pics/gifs/042/100/151/42100151a.webm"
    data-mp4="https://el.phncdn.com/pics/gifs/042/100/151/42100151a.mp4"
    　　　poster="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"
    data-poster="https://el.phncdn.com/pics/gifs/042/100/151/(m=bKOCwLV)(mh=LC91wp1cr3v8n- 
Nk)42100151a.jpg" loop muted>
    <source class="js-webm" type="video/webm">
    <source class="js-mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

`data-` から始まる [データ属性](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)、今回の場合は `data-webm`, `data-mp4` などが該当します、はJavaScript(やCSS)からアクセスされることを想定したものです。

したがって、おそらく `https://el.phncdn.com/pics/gifs/042/100/151/42100151a.webm` か `https://el.phncdn.com/pics/gifs/042/100/151/42100151a.mp4` がソースなのだろう、という予想は付きますが、実際にどちらなのかはJSも見る必要があります。
JSで何らかの条件でどちらをソースとして採用するかを判断し`src`へ設定する、といったような処理を行っていると考えられます。

Answer (score 0):

その情報だけでは確信を持って言えることはありません。

- JavaScript コードで `data-webm` か `data-mp4` の属性値を使っているのかもしれません。
- JavaScript コードで、それ以外のデータからセットしているのかもしれません。